# Zref package, hyperref not working

Tags: cross-referencing, zref

I am using zref for crossreferencing from one file to another. But my Hyperreferencing is not working. Here's the code

Main.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\zexternaldocument*{trail2}



\begin{document}
Hi, \zref{S1}
\end{document}
```

trail2.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}


\begin{document}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering \Large

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{trail_picture}

\caption{\label{S1} trail-picture }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zref is not really prepared for hyperlinking (or hyperref not really prepared for zref).

So either you should use the normal \ref command which hyperref redefines, or you will have to build your own ref command with the infos provided by zref. E.g.

(this is only a draft, I didn't really try to check if all special chars are handled correctly).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref} %needed by zref-xr

\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-hyperref,zref-user}

\zxrsetup{toltxlabel=true}

\zexternaldocument*{trail2}

{\catcode`\#=12 \gdef\hashchar{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hzref[1]{\edef\next{%
    \noexpand\href{%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{url}{}%
      \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{anchor}{%
      \hashchar\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{}}%
      {\noexpand\zref{#1}}}\next}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{S1}, \zref{S1}, \hzref{S1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: I didn't think that zref and hyperref were incompatible. I typically use both and don't seem to have an issue. Just double checked, and section/figure hyperlinks work fine while still pulling labels from another document.

Comment: @Sterling: I didn't wrote incompatible, only that some functions are not supported, and the question here is one example.